# How to loop through directory and only return folder names through a web method using C#?

Tags: c#, webmethod

I'm trying to read a directory using C# and return all the folder names in that directory. I do not want any nested folders or files to be returned, only the immediate folders in the directory.

I'm going to use these names to build a side nav in my application. Users will have the ability to create new folders so I want the nav to be dynamically built as new folders get created over time. I have tried to different solutions thus far.

1st - I used `Directory.GetFiles()` and looped through directory but this returns every single folder and file name found in the whole directory.

2nd - I used `Directory.GetDirectory()` and tried looping through the directory and this does return just the folder name, but only the first folder! I need the remaining folders. It's like my loop is not working.

1st Try:

```
 string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\\\SERVERNAME\\Data\\ServerLinks\\Safety\\","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
    string File = "";
    for (int ii = 0; ii < files.Length; ii++)
    {
        File += "|" + files[ii];
    }
    return (File);
```

2nd Try:

```
string path = @"\\\\SERVERNAME\\Data\\ServerLinks\\Safety\\";
    foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        string name = folder.Remove(0, folder.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        return (name);            
    }
    return ("");
```

Comment: The reason your second try returns only one item is that it returns *from inside the loop*. The GetDirectories is the right method...but use it like you did in the first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt is in the correct direction. You are just returning on the first folder. Instead you should store all the folders and return the collection. Or just do a yield return to return as an `IEnumerable`

```
var allFolders = new List<string>();
string path = @"\\SERVERNAME\Data\ServerLinks\Safety\";
foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {
    string name = folder.Remove(0, folder.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    allFolders.Add(name)
}
return allFolders;
```

If I were you, I would use a slightly different code which is lot more robust and idiomatic

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name);
```

Instead of using the `Directory` class and then doing path manipulations using string functions, you can keep information as a Directory object with `new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories()`. I have just done a select on the `DirectoryInfo.Name`, since that's what your code was showing, but you have a more powerful `DirectoryInfo` object available at your disposal with this way

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks Vikhram!